# Adding a directory to PATH in visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to add a bunch of libraries to python while using visual studio. I downloaded python using the microsoft store, but have downloaded everything else using pip, which doesn't download to the same place. How do I adjust the path, or where do I need to move files to ensure that I can import everything properly?

Answer (score 0):

Open workspace Settings.json, add

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "\the folder that contains modules\",
]
```

Then in python file, before importing modules, add

```
import sys
sys.path.append("\the folder that contains modules\")
```

See the following picture, there's no `discord` in current interpreter and with above settings and code, it can be import successfully. Please have a try.
[image]